# Backbone + RequireJs-jQuery : Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have this situation:

js/main.js

```
require.config({
    'baseUrl' : 'js',
    'waitSeconds' : 45,
    'paths': {
        "underscore": "libs/underscore-min",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-min",
        "text" : "text"
    },
    'shim': {
        backbone: {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            'exports': '_'
        }
    },
    'config': {
        i18n: {
            locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en-en'
        }
    }
});

require(['underscore', 'backbone', 'app'], function(_, Backbone, app) {

    window.APP = window.APP || {};
    app.init();
});
```

js/app.js

```
define(['jquery', 'routers/home'], function($, router) {

    var init = function() {

        APP.router = new router();

        $("body").css({
            overflow: 'hidden'
        });

    };
    return {
        init: init
    };
});
```

I have this error - Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined

On some module i use css plugin and i use text for template..
I miss something? What mean this error?
Thanks

Edit:
this is my Inspector log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined require-jquery.js:929
(anonymous function) require-jquery.js:929
(anonymous function) require-jquery.js:130
(anonymous function) require-jquery.js:1128
each require-jquery.js:58
Module.emit require-jquery.js:1127
Module.check require-jquery.js:899
Module.enable require-jquery.js:1115
Module.init require-jquery.js:758
callGetModule require-jquery.js:1142
context.completeLoad require-jquery.js:1493
context.onScriptLoad require-jquery.js:1620
```

Comment: where exactly is there error coming from? which js file? can you see in developer console / firebug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add jquery to your paths:

```
require.config({
    'baseUrl' : 'js',
    'waitSeconds' : 45,
    'paths': {
        //right here
        "jquery": "path/to/jquery",
        "underscore": "libs/underscore-min",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-min",
        "text" : "text"
    },
    //other stuff
});
```

Comment: I use require-jquery.js, so i think i don't need to add it. is it right?

Comment: No, you need to have paths for all of your libraries in your config.